# XSS prevention: client or server-side?

Tags: security, xss, owasp

What is the best way of **prevention from stored XSS** ?

- should every text field (even plain text) be sanitized **server-side** to prevent from XSS HTML using something like [OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project)?
- or should the **client** protect itself from XSS bugs by applying [XSS prevention rules](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)?

The problem with the first solution is that data may be modified (character encoding, partial or total deletion...). Which can alter the behavior of the application, especially for display concerns.

Comment: Security is best in layers, so both and then some is best. BTW, this is more security-opinion-based than programming-based, https://security.stackexchange.com might be a better place for it.

Answer (score 5):

You apply *sanitisation* if and only if your data needs to conform to a specific format/standard and you are sure you can safely *discard data*; e.g. you strip all non-numeric characters from a telephone or credit card number. You *always* apply escaping for the appropriate context, e.g. HTML-encode user-supplied data when putting it into HTML.

Most of the time you don't want to sanitise, because you want to explicitly allow freeform data input and disallowing certain characters simply makes little sense. One of the few exceptions I see here would be if you're accepting HTML input from your users, you will want to sanitise that HTML to filter out unwanted tags and attributes and ensure the syntax is valid; however, you'd probably want to store the raw, unsanitised version in the database and apply this sanitisation only on output.

Comment: It should be "always apply sanitization except when you want to allow freeform data input," most of the time you do want to sanitize.

Answer (score 4):

The gold standard in security is: Validate your inputs, and *encode*, not sanitize, your outputs.

First, validate the input server side. A good example of this would be a phone number field on a user profile. Phone numbers should only consist of digits, dashes, and perhaps a +. So why allow users to submit letters, special characters, etc? It only increases attack surface. So validate that field as strictly as you can, and reject bad inputs.

Second, encode the output according to its output context. I'd recommend doing this step server side as well, but it's relatively safe to do client side as long as you are using a good, well tested front-end framework. The main problem with sanitization is that different contexts have different requirements for safety. To prevent XSS when you are injecting user data into an HTML attribute, directly into the page, or into a script tag, you need to do different things. So, you create specific output encoders based on the output context. Entity encode for the HTML context, JSON.stringify for the script context, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The client has to defend against this. For two reasons:

- Because this is where the vulnerability happens.  You might be calling a 3rd party API and they haven't escaped / encoded everything.  It is better not trust anything.
- Second, the API could be written for HTML page and for Android App.  So why should the server html encode what some may consider html tags in a request when on the way back out it may be going to android app?